# How to export dataset elements from Birt to .docx as numbered list

Tags: report, birt, export-to-word

I have a birt report which contains numbered list of questions. It built with some dataset elements + label (text).

[image: 1]
But after exporting it to .docx numbers usually merge with the text (as a part of text). I need it to be splitted  out of the text (as the formatted numbered list in MS Word).
What can I do?

I expect of splitted numberes and question text

Comment: Good question. BIRT itself does not support the concept of numbered list. So it's probably not possible to create auto-numbered list items (which would support inserting items inbetween with automatic renumbering.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I doubt this is possible.

If you can live with a different structure that more or less has the same properties regarding visual appearance and editability (does that word exist?), what I do is:

- Use something like a RUNNINGCOUNT aggregate to generate the item numbers.
- Use a two-column table to render the ordered list: Left column contains the number, right column contains the text.

This takes care of the visual appearance.
To insert items inbetween manually later, one can insert a row into the table, but it's necessary to re-number the following items manually.